# Crash caused by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: for custom cell

Tags: ios, tableview

### Update - A Workaround

I find a work around by doing these: (But I still don't understand why in the `dealloc` we have to use `[_profileImage release];` in this case even if we don't own, neither `alloc` nor `new` nor `copy`, `_profileImage`)

**MyUITableView.m**

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_profileImage release];
    // and all other ivars get released here

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)onClickLogoutButton {
    if (_profileImage != nil) {
        _profileImage = nil;
    }
    // and other operations
}
```

The crash occurs when I have a `[_profileImage release];` in `onClickLogoutButton`, because I don't own (neither `alloc` nor `new` nor `copy`) `_profileImage`, but just use `_profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];` to pass object to `_profileImage`:

```
- (void)onClickLogoutButton {
    if (_profileImage != nil) {
        [_profileImage release];
        _profileImage = nil;
    }
    // and other operations
}
```

### Original Problem

This following code uses manual retain-release (MRR), in Xcode 5, iOS 7.

`ProfileCell *cell = (ProfileCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierForProfileCell];` causes a crash, one of the error message is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x2448c90c)`

Is it because I release something mistakenly? But I'm not sure where and when and what get released. There is a logout function in the project, after logout should we release something or just let dealloc to do the job? The error occurs when first login, then logout and then re-login, scroll to the profile cell, and crash.

Should I call `[self reloadData];` in `MyUITableView.m` after logout?

**MyUITableView.m**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewLeft cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //ProfileCell
    if ([indexPath section] == 0 && [indexPath row] == 0) {
        static NSString *identifierForProfileCell   = @"ProfileCell";

        ProfileCell *cell = (ProfileCell *)[tableViewLeft dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierForProfileCell]; // This line causes crash: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x2448c90c)

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[ProfileCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifierForProfileCell] autorelease];
        }

        [[cell textField] setText:_userID];
        if (_profileImage == nil && _profileURL != nil) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_profileURL];
            NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response, NSData * data, NSError * error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        _profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        [[cell iconView] setImage:_profileImage];
                    }
                }];
            }

            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSetting:)];
            [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
            [cell.settingWrapper addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
            [singleTap release];
            return cell;
        }
    } else {
        // ....
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to comment out the static NSString, and directly place @"menuProfileCell" in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method call ?

Comment: To @Vinzzz, let me have a try...

Comment: To @Vinzzz, still crash using @"menuProfileCell" directly

Comment: To @Vinzzz, is it because I release something mistakenly? But I'm not sure where and when and what get released. There is a logout function in the project, after logout should we release something or just let dealloc to do the job? The error occurs when first login, then logout and then re-login, scroll to the profile cell, and crash.

Comment: MenuProfileCell extend  ProfileCell?

Comment: To @GuilhermeTorresCastro, There is only ProfileCell, ignore that `menu` word, I should write it as @"ProfileCell" instead.

Comment: note : if you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` on an un-registered cell identifier, this WILL crash. Make sure you called `-UITableView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `-UITableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in your `viewDidLoad` (BEFORE `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is called)

Comment: To @Vinzzz, em! I'll try it now!

Comment: To @Vinzzz, but why must use registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: in viewDidLoad not in some table view delegate method?

Comment: To @Vinzzz, added `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in `viewDidLoad` but still crash at `ProfileCell *cell = (ProfileCell *)[tableViewLeft dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierForProfileCell];` Sometimes the crash occurs at `[[cell iconView] setImage:_profileImage];`

Comment: To @Vinzzz please have a look of my solution update, there's still something not clear.

Answer (score 4):

Have you register the ProfileCell in the tableView before?

Like this in viewDidLoad :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:ProfileCell  forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ProfileCell"];
  }
```

Comment: To @louftansa, I've added `[[self tableView] registerClass:[ProfileCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ProfileCell"];` in `viewDidLoad`, still crash at the original place.

Comment: are you sure your `tableView` property isn't nil?

Comment: To @Vinzzz, I init _tableView in the custom `-(id)init` method, is it before `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: To @Vinzzz, and program's logout function doesn't cause `dealloc` to run?